# How to measure requests per user and minute

Tags: php

At first I want to say that **request** doesn't mean '**mysql query**'

**So what request mean?** I answer to it on example.

- I have ajax script, that refers to php page.
- Script send some data, also user id who request this page.
- This php do something code.

**Question:**

How many times in a one minute, every user **request** this **php** page? 
How to measure it in high performance?

Comment: Please remove the MySQL tag, unless you have a database component.  If the data is stored in MySQL, then provide examples of the data and the table layouts.

Comment: what do you want to know request on web server or DB server....

Comment: I put the MySQL tag because, I thought that I should store this data in mysql.

Comment: @ThomasBanderas How do you identify a single user? By IP? By user agent? Cookies? Sessions? Should your system stand up to users that actively try to circumvent it?

Comment: I said user_id it is identify which is send by ajax. I can bind user_id with an user in mysql and take ip, user_name, unique token...
I thought that I should made a new mysql table
`id | visit_time | user_id` and collect data, but it is a high performance?

Comment: @ThomasBanderas don't worry about performance. At all. Stuff like this cost you virtually nothing. Start worrying when your page has a few thousand hits an hour. And even then, I bet you can gain performance boost on other places then a simple insert query.

Answer (score -1):

At the beginning of your php scripts you can retrieve info about the request from the `$_SERVER` global variable. If you `var_dump` the `$_SERVER` variable you can see what information is available about the request. I imagine that something like `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` will hold the info that you need. Store that info plus the user id and the date in a mysql table and you should be set?